# How to import Table and Data to SQL Server Database Project in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: sql-server, import

So, I have a solution file which consists of a ASP.Net MVC Application and a SQL Server Database Project. Both are checked in to TFS. I know how to import the database, table, views, functions and stored procedures, but I want to the tables to have data as well. How can I import the table with data?

Comment: You can define scripts to run as part of a sqlproj that will insert data into tables. I've seen it used for inserting basic configuration data. Have you looked into that? What does your question have to do with ASP.NET?

Comment: Thanks for reply @mason . It has nothing to do with asp.net. That was a typo mistake. Can you share any link to define scripts as a part of sqlproject? I am new to it, so don't have much idea

Comment: In the Solution Explorer, right click your project and go to Add, then Script. Choose a Post Deployment Script or a Pre Deployment Script. Doing so will add a .sql file to your project, and set the build action appropriately so that it will either run before or after your schema has been created. In this case since you want to add data, you need a Post Deployment Script. If you need to control the order in which data is added, you can add it all in the same file, or just add a single post deployment script and have it invoke other .sql files.

Comment: Thanks @mason. You're genius !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define scripts to run as part of a sqlproj that will insert data into tables. I've seen it used for inserting basic configuration data.

In the Solution Explorer, right click your project and go to Add, then Script. Choose a Post Deployment Script or a Pre Deployment Script. Doing so will add a .sql file to your project, and set the build action appropriately so that it will either run before or after your schema has been created. In this case since you want to add data, you need a Post Deployment Script. If you need to control the order in which data is added, you can add it all in the same file, or just add a single post deployment script and have it invoke other .sql files.